# Execute permission while creating shell script

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts

Can I provide execute permission to a shell script while creating it for the first time?

I want a line of code which allows me to give execute permission to a file so that I can add that line inside the file itself. Assume that I know the filename beforehand.

Comment: You want to write a script file that is able to enable its own execution permission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you want a script file that sets its own execution permission, you have to include this command:

```
chmod +x -- "$0"
```

The shell variable `$0` always holds the name of the running script. Note the double quotes and double dash to protect misinterpretation of special file names.

However, to launch that script the first time, you need to call the interpreter with the script file as argument, like this:

```
bash example.sh
```

Comment: Why is the however bit important?! Also why should we still call it with `bash`?

Comment: @NelsonGon Back then, I interpreted the question as that you want to have a script which adds execute permissions *to itself* once you run it, so that *subsequent* runs can be done by launching it directly instead of passing it as argument to the interpreter. That means before the first run, the file would not be executable yet though, hence you need to run it with the interpreter explicitly once.

Comment: Yes, it's actually what I was looking for and your answer seems to do that. I'm however just not sure why we need to run it again with `bash` infront. I'm new to `bash` btw, are they cases when we can simply omit the bash and have the script execute?

Comment: When it runs the first time and the script is not marked as executable yet, you need to write `bash example.sh`. After that (or after running `chmod +x example.sh`) the script is executable and you can just `./example.sh` or `path/to/example.sh` to run it, without `bash`. That also requires a correct shebang (first line of the file being `#!/bin/bash`) though.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the detailed explanation. I kinda find that giving it the ability to make itself executable is not very "efficient" because a user still has to type `chmod +x file.sh` on first run. Would be nice if the user would just call it and it auto self permits.

Answer (score 2):

```
chmod +x /path/to/file
```

If you are using a script to make a script you will not have a issue, however you can't use a script to give itself permission to execute, well you can but by that point it is pointless

you can also run a script lacking permission like this

```
sh /path/to/script.sh
bash /path/to/script
python /path/to/script.py
php /path/to/script.php
```